# python - "from utils import label_map_util" ImportError: cannot import name 'label_map_util'

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I am running this code i get an import errror

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("ipr.mp4")

from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90



opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())



detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')



label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)



with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

error:

> warning: Error opening file
>   (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:834) warning:
>   ipr.mp4 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:835)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 31, in
>   
>       from utils import label_map_util ImportError: cannot import name 'label_map_util'

Comment: if you eliminate ALL the code except for the line "from utils import label_map_util", do you get the same ImportError ?

Comment: Yes i get the same error

Comment: then you can simplify your post with only the relevant information for your question

Answer (score 14):

CD to object_detection directory

```
import( os )
os.chdir( 'D:\\projects\\data core\\helmet detection\\models\\research\\object_detection' )
```

and change these lines

```
from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

to the following lines

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

It will work.

Source : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1990

Comment: what is your working directory from which you are running the code ?

Comment: D:\Pythonic\My-Work

Comment: Clone this https://github.com/tensorflow/models and there you will find a folder called ..\\models\\research\\object_detection - then run the above code. It will work.

Comment: The code label_map_util lies in a folder named utils in the object_detection directory

Comment: @RoxasZohbi, if this answer satisfies/satisfied your need, please accept it. People will notice it faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. However, in order to make it work I had to do the following:

1. Create a virtual environment with the following:
   i) OpenCV 4.0.1
   ii) Python 3.6
   iii) tensorflow v1.12
2. Install and/or update the various dependencies individually:
   conda install scipy
   pip install --upgrade sklearn
   pip install --upgrade pandas
   pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
   pip install --upgrade matplotlib
   pip install --upgrade pillow
   pip install --upgrade requests
   pip install --upgrade h5py
   pip install --upgrade pyyaml
   pip install --upgrade psutil
   pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.12.0
   pip install -- upgrade lxml
   pip install opencv-contrib-python
3. Compile all the protocol buffer definition files:
   i)cd to the models/research folder
   ii)protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

4.Export the correct PYTHONPATH variable path:
    i)export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
   ii)echo $PYTHONPATH

5. Go to the folder where the file resides (object_dectection) and run it in python
   i) cd object_detection/
   ii) python test_pyprog.py