# Tensorflow Webcam Object Detection Not starting

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow

when i try to start my object_detection.py it gives me this error

```
C:\Users\Tensorflow\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python object_detection.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection.py", line 26, in <module>
    from utils import label_map_util
  File "C:\Users\Tensorflow\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
  File "C:\Users\Tensorflow\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\object_detection.py", line 28, in <module>
    from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
  File "C:\Users\Tensorflow\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 41, in <module>
    from object_detection.core import keypoint_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection.core'; 'object_detection' is not a package
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

things that i have tryed to solve this problem

```
Executing this: setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0                  (no result)
Executing this: SET PYTHONPATH=%cd%:%cd%\slim                        (no result)
Using the installer to add Python to environment variables           (no result)
Executing this: pip install object-detection     (Requirement already satisfied)
Using python3 to execute                                             (no result)
[Using Python3 to execute][1]
```

Comment: Have you tried "pip install object-detection"?

Comment: @Ahmet
i havent tryed that but it gives me the message 
`Requirement already satisfied:`

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? Its possible you are trying to run the script not from where the package is installed.

Comment: i am not using a viritual envioriment i am using a viritual machine and i have goten this to work before.

Comment: @MinebloxSr, Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569669/python-from-utils-import-label-map-util-importerror-cannot-import-name-lab) or [this](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/issues/58) answers your question ? Thanks!